# R: if_else and timezone forcing

Tags: r, if-statement, lubridate, posixct

I have a weird problem (maybe I'm missing something?), when trying to force timezone within `if_else` (as `ifelse` does not seem to handle `POSIXct` well). It seems to force only when `TRUE`, but convert when `FALSE`. Why? How to fix it?

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
some_date = ymd_hm("2020-06-01 17:45", tz = "America/New_York")

if_else(TRUE, force_tz(some_date, tz = "GMT"), force_tz(some_date, tz = "Singapore"))
[1] "2020-06-01 17:45:00 GMT"

if_else(FALSE, force_tz(some_date, tz = "GMT"), force_tz(some_date, tz = "Singapore"))
[1] "2020-06-01 09:45:00 GMT"
```

I would expect the same outcome as running force_tz alone:

```
# if TRUE
force_tz(some_date, tz = "GMT")
[1] "2020-06-01 17:45:00 GMT"

# if FALSE
force_tz(some_date, tz = "Singapore")
[1] "2020-06-01 17:45:00 +08"
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you're dealing with `POSIXt` in a *vector*, the TZ is an attribute of the whole vector, not each independent element. This means that either (a) you must accept that all timestamps within a vector will have the same TZ; or (b) you need to adapt your process to deal with a `list` of timestamps, in which case each time *can* have its own TZ.

Comment: (And yes, `POSIXt` class is one place where base `ifelse` is unfit.)

Comment: This was a useful question for me. I wasn't trying to force_tz, but only preserve the existing time zone, but if_else kept switching me back to my local tz rather than UTC. I had to put `with_tz` in both my FALSE and my TRUE conditions to keep it in both places. (the problem wasn't with `mutate()`, only when I added `if_else()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is in *how* `dplyr::if_else` is making the adjustments.

First, my original comment about vectors and TZ still stands, and is still at the heart of this problem. For the record:

> When you're dealing with `POSIXt` in a *vector*, the TZ is an attribute of the whole vector, not each independent element. This means that either (a) you must accept that all timestamps within a vector will have the same TZ; or (b) you need to adapt your process to deal with a `list` of timestamps, in which case each time can have its own TZ.

If you look at `if_else`:

```r
function (condition, true, false, missing = NULL) 
{
    if (!is.logical(condition)) {
        bad_args("condition", "must be a logical vector, not {friendly_type_of(condition)}")
    }
    out <- true[rep(NA_integer_, length(condition))]
```

which prepopulates the `out` vector with `NA` variants of the first ("true") vector. (This is necessary because R really has at least 6 types of `NA`: logical (`NA`), integer (`NA_integer_`), real/float (`NA_real_`), string (`NA_character_`), date (`c.Date(NA)`), and time (`c.POSIXct(NA)`); so *how* one forms a vector of `NA` is important.) Once the vector of `NA`s is prepopulated, though, realize that this is being based on the first vector, so its attributes are brought into the `out` vector.

```r
Sys.time()
# [1] "2020-06-01 09:02:06 PDT"
now <- Sys.time()
attr(now, "tzone") <- "GMT"
dput(now)
# structure(1591027335.41804, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")
dput(now[NA])
# structure(NA_real_, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")
```

(see how `tzone=` is still the same). This means that the output vector (when operating on `POSIXt` vectors)`will always carry forward the TZ of the`true`argument to`if_else`.

From here, `if_else` works in *replacement* (using its internal `replace_with`, which effectively just does `out[condition] <- false[condition]`). Replacement does *not* affect the TZ; in fact, the numeric equivalents of the `false` times are assimilated without regard to their TZ. Granted, the "absolute time in the world" for the `false` vector is preserved.

The only workaround is to change your workflow to deal with a `list` of `POSIXt` instead of a vector. `if_else` still works there.

```r
now
# [1] "2020-06-01 16:02:15 GMT"
now1 <- list(now, now+1) ; now2 <- list(now+86400, now+86401)
now1
# [[1]]
# [1] "2020-06-01 16:02:15 GMT"
# [[2]]
# [1] "2020-06-01 16:02:16 GMT"
now2
# [[1]]
# [1] "2020-06-02 16:02:15 GMT"
# [[2]]
# [1] "2020-06-02 16:02:16 GMT"
attr(now1[[2]], "tzone") <- "Singapore"
attr(now2[[2]], "tzone") <- "US/Pacific"
now1
# [[1]]
# [1] "2020-06-01 16:02:15 GMT"
# [[2]]
# [1] "2020-06-02 00:02:16 +08"
now2
# [[1]]
# [1] "2020-06-02 16:02:15 GMT"
# [[2]]
# [1] "2020-06-02 09:02:16 PDT"
if_else(c(TRUE, FALSE), now1, now2)
# [[1]]
# [1] "2020-06-01 16:02:15 GMT"
# [[2]]
# [1] "2020-06-02 09:02:16 PDT"
```